# A Noetherian-as-a-module ring is Noetherian as a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, ideals, noetherian

[This SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/651579/673223) <s>claims</s> [see the edit] (in the beginning paragraph) that if $A$, $B$ are rings with $B$ being Noetherian as an $A$-module, then $B$ is Noetherian as a ring because

> any chain of $B$-ideals is a chain of $A$-submodules of $B$.

However, I am not able to see this. I guess what I need to show is that any $B$-ideal $\mathfrak b$ is also an $A$-submodule of $B$. But I am unable to prove closure-under-scalar-multiplication for $\mathfrak b$.

Can you help?

**Edit:**

I realised that the linked answer was also working with the hypothesis that $A$ is a subring of $B$.

So, I ask if this is true for arbitrary rings $A$, $B$.

Comment: The hypothesis you seem to miss is that there is a ring homomorphism $f:A\to B$ and that the $A$-module structure is induced by $f$. Any ideal is closed under multiplication by elements of $B$ whence also under multiplication by elements of $f(A)$.

Comment: @reuns I agree that this hypothesis will make the statement true. But this raises another question! Is the scalar multiplication necessarily induced by such a ring homomorphism $A\to B$?

Comment: No. $\Bbb{R}^2$ and $\Bbb{C}$ have the same addition but not the same multiplication.

Comment: @reuns This settles it! Thanks!